# Translate rails nested attributes of a model with a prefix name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, prefix, rails-i18n

My project have two models with prefix name:
**Professional::Company** and **Professional::Service**

The **Professional::Company** model

```
class Professional::Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :professional_services, class_name: 'Professional::Service',
                                       dependent: :destroy,
                                       foreign_key: 'professional_company_id',
                                       inverse_of: :professional_company  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :professional_services  
end
```

The **Professional::Service** model

```
class Professional::Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :professional_company, class_name: 'Professional::Company',
                                    foreign_key: 'professional_company_id',
                                    inverse_of: :professional_services
end
```

**pt-Br.yml**

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      professional/company:
        name: 'Name'
        description: 'Description'
      professional/service:
        description: 'Description service'
        name: 'Title service'
```

I'm saving **Professional::Company** with nested attributes of **Professional::Service**.
In errors case how i can translate 
 Professional::Service nested attributes?

Comment: Please add more details to your post; it's not enough to answer yet.

Comment: It's best now ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this with the code bellow

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      professional/company:
        name: 'Name'
        description: 'Description'
      professional/service:
        description: 'Description service'
        name: 'Title service'
      professional/company/professional_services:
        description: 'Description service'
        name: 'Title service'
```

basically you need put this code in attributes level:

```
 prefix/model_name/method_of_association: 
    nested_attribute: 'The translate'
```